# Grouped bar plot on the x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a problem. I would like to print a grouped bar plot (with seaborn or matplotlib). When I run the below snippet code I got

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

```py
d = {'type': ['House', 'Boat', 'Bus', 'Bus', 'Boat'], 'room': ['private', 'public', 'public', 'private', 'nothing']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

[OUT]

    type     room
0  House  private
1   Boat   public
2    Bus   public
3    Bus  private
4   Boat  nothing

g = sns.catplot(
    data=df, kind="bar",
    x='type', y=df.groupby(['type']).count(), hue="room",
    palette="dark", alpha=.6, height=6
)
g.despine(left=True)
g.set_axis_labels("", "Counts")
g.legend.set_title("")

[OUT]
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What I want

[image]

Comment: The correct way is with pandas `pd.crosstab(df.type, df.room).plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=0)`

Comment: Otherwise `g = sns.catplot(data=df, kind="count", x='type', hue="room", palette="dark", alpha=.6, height=6)` for side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this would do the trick:

```
pd.crosstab(df['type'],df['room']).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image]